# Need a VB.net Combobox derived class for pattern matched or contains autocomplete functionality

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox, autocomplete, derived-class

Ive searched everywhere on the net for a solution to this common pain. Surely someone out there has a solution or can help me implement one ????

Basically the default combobox in vb.net autocompletes using a limited "StartsWith" pattern match (for example, when you type any letter, only the listitems.text that start with that letter will be filtered and shown in the dropdownlist.

There isnt an obviously simple switch to change the way these are filtered and so I assume that the best way to solve this issue is to derive/inherit the combobox class and modify it to use String.contains() ?? Only issue i have never done a derived class and would really appreciate some help with this specific problem.

Also, I found a C# solution that seems to exactly solve this issue (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S) and ive tried everything to convert or code something similar with little success :(

Im amazed this is still unsolved, since so many people on the net have asked for a solution to this limitation !!!!

Comment: Any reason you can't use the c# example you found?  It could be compiled into an assembly as-is then referenced from your vb.net project

Comment: ...and (in addition to what James said) that code is also pretty small and should be easy to convert in VB.NET (if you want).

Comment: Many Thanks for your comments.. Truth is compiling the

Comment: Many Thanks for your comments.. I guess your right, but mixing/compiling the c# assembly and including it into my large vb.net project isnt an elegant nor systematic approach to what Im trying to achieve. Moreover, i have tried at least 4 different C# to VB converters, in addition to compiling the assembly and using .net reflector to rebuild the code in vb also produced little usable code :(

Comment: Am i asking too much in VB.net ? Is this why no solution can be found ??

Comment: how is that "inelegant"?  according to whom?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done in VB.NET. I was on the same thought process of that you could just try converting the code in the link you posted from C# to VB.NET as the previous comments suggested. However when I tried doing so the resulting VB wouldn't compile. After fixing numerous build errors and some syntax errors I present to you the VB version of the `SuggestComboBox` and how it is used. The only reason why I'm posting this answer is because the conversion from C# to VB wasn't straightforward, and the license the source is released under allows me to do so.

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S)

[License](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx)

You need to add the control via the code behind of the form, I couldn't find a designer portion in the source (blame my lacking knowledge of C# on that).

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim testbox As New AutoCompleteComboBox.SuggestComboBox
        Me.Controls.Add(testbox)
        testbox.DataSource = New List(Of String) From {"Janean Mcgaha", "Tama Gaitan", "Jacque Tinnin", "Elvira Woolfolk", "Fransisca Owens", "Minnie Ardoin", _
        "Renay Bentler", "Joye Boyter", "Jaime Flannery", "Maryland Arai", "Walton Edelstein", "Nereida Storrs", _
        "Theron Zinn", "Katharyn Estrella", "Alline Dubin", "Edra Bhatti", "Willa Jeppson", "Chelsea Revel", _
        "Sonya Lowy", "Danelle Kapoor"}
    End Sub
End Class

Namespace AutoCompleteComboBox
    Public Class SuggestComboBox
        Inherits ComboBox
#Region "fields and properties"

        Private ReadOnly _suggLb As New ListBox() With {.Visible = False, .TabStop = False}
        Private ReadOnly _suggBindingList As New BindingList(Of String)()
        Private _propertySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
        Private _propertySelectorCompiled As Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))
        Private _filterRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
        Private _filterRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, Boolean)
        Private _suggestListOrderRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
        Private _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, String)

        Public Property SuggestBoxHeight() As Integer
            Get
                Return _suggLb.Height
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                If value > 0 Then
                    _suggLb.Height = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' If the item-type of the ComboBox is not string,
        ''' you can set here which property should be used
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property PropertySelector() As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
            Get
                Return _propertySelector
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _propertySelector = value
                _propertySelectorCompiled = value.Compile()
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        ''' Lambda-Expression to determine the suggested items
        ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
        ''' <para>default: case-insensitive contains search</para>
        ''' <para>1st string: list item</para>
        ''' <para>2nd string: typed text</para>
        '''</summary>
        Public Property FilterRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
            Get
                Return _filterRule
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean)))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _filterRule = value
                _filterRuleCompiled = Function(item) value.Compile()(item, Text)
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        ''' Lambda-Expression to order the suggested items
        ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
        ''' <para>default: alphabetic ordering</para>
        '''</summary>
        Public Property SuggestListOrderRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
            Get
                Return _suggestListOrderRule
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String)))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _suggestListOrderRule = value
                _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = value.Compile()
            End Set
        End Property

#End Region

        ''' <summary>
        ''' ctor
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
            ' set the standard rules:
            _filterRuleCompiled = Function(s) s.ToLower().Contains(Text.Trim().ToLower())
            _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = Function(s) s
            _propertySelectorCompiled = Function(collection) collection.Cast(Of String)()

            _suggLb.DataSource = _suggBindingList
            AddHandler _suggLb.Click, AddressOf SuggLbOnClick

            AddHandler ParentChanged, AddressOf OnParentChanged
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' the magic happens here ;-)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)

            If Not Focused Then
                Return
            End If

            _suggBindingList.Clear()
            _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
            _propertySelectorCompiled(Items).Where(_filterRuleCompiled).OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled).ToList().ForEach(AddressOf _suggBindingList.Add)
            _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
            _suggBindingList.ResetBindings()

            _suggLb.Visible = _suggBindingList.Any()

            If _suggBindingList.Count = 1 AndAlso _suggBindingList.[Single]().Length = Text.Trim().Length Then
                Text = _suggBindingList.[Single]()
                [Select](0, Text.Length)
                _suggLb.Visible = False
            End If
        End Sub

#Region "size and position of suggest box"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' suggest-ListBox is added to parent control
        ''' (in ctor parent isn't already assigned)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Private Overloads Sub OnParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Parent.Controls.Add(_suggLb)
            Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(_suggLb, 0)
            _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
            _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
            _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
            _suggLb.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 9)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLocationChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnLocationChanged(e)
            _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
            _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
            _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "visibility of suggest box"

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(e As EventArgs)
            ' _suggLb can only getting focused by clicking (because TabStop is off)
            ' --> click-eventhandler 'SuggLbOnClick' is called
            If Not _suggLb.Focused Then
                HideSuggBox()
            End If
            MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
        End Sub

        Private Sub SuggLbOnClick(sender As Object, eventArgs As EventArgs)
            Text = _suggLb.Text
            Focus()
        End Sub

        Private Sub HideSuggBox()
            _suggLb.Visible = False
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(e As EventArgs)
            HideSuggBox()
            MyBase.OnDropDown(e)
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "keystroke events"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' if the suggest-ListBox is visible some keystrokes
        ''' should behave in a custom way
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnPreviewKeyDown(e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
            If Not _suggLb.Visible Then
                MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
                Return
            End If

            Select Case e.KeyCode
                Case Keys.Down
                    If _suggLb.SelectedIndex < _suggBindingList.Count - 1 Then
                        _suggLb.SelectedIndex += 1
                    End If
                    Return
                Case Keys.Up
                    If _suggLb.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
                        _suggLb.SelectedIndex -= 1
                    End If
                    Return
                Case Keys.Enter
                    Text = _suggLb.Text
                    [Select](0, Text.Length)
                    _suggLb.Visible = False
                    Return
                Case Keys.Escape
                    HideSuggBox()
                    Return
            End Select

            MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
        End Sub

        Private Shared ReadOnly KeysToHandle As List(Of Keys) = New List(Of Keys) From {Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape}
        Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
            ' the keysstrokes of our interest should not be processed be base class:
            If _suggLb.Visible AndAlso KeysToHandle.Contains(keyData) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
        End Function

#End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Brandon,I cannot thank you enough for your invaluable support, effort and amazing result. I honestly tried for days to convert it and had so many issues and never got it anywhere near your result.

Comment: Brandon, I tried to mark it as an answer it says it already is ! and also i tried upvoting it but it says Vote Up Requires Minimum 15 reputation :(