# Variable value lost within 2 classes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, class, variables, autocomplete

I have tried the autocomplete code from here :

[Need a VB.net Combobox derived class for pattern matched or contains autocomplete functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050133/need-a-vb-net-combobox-derived-class-for-pattern-matched-or-contains-autocomplet)

I added some code and I really don't understand why the NbrName is lost.

I added :

```
    Case Keys.Enter
                Text = _suggLb.Text
                [Select](0, Text.Length)
                _suggLb.Visible = False

                'Mika
                Dim myObject As Form1 = New Form1()
                myObject.SearchByName(Text)
                'Mika
    Return
```

and this :

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Mika Dim testbox As New AutoCompleteComboBox.SuggestComboBox
    Me.Controls.Add(testbox)
    testbox.DataSource = New List(Of String) From {"Janean Mcgaha", "Tama Gaitan", "Jacque Tinnin", "Elvira Woolfolk", "Fransisca Owens", "Minnie Ardoin",
    "Renay Bentler", "Joye Boyter", "Jaime Flannery", "Maryland Arai", "Walton Edelstein", "Nereida Storrs",
    "Theron Zinn", "Katharyn Estrella", "Alline Dubin", "Edra Bhatti", "Willa Jeppson", "Chelsea Revel",
    "Sonya Lowy", "Danelle Kapoor"}

    NbrName = 20
End Sub

Public Sub SearchByName(text As String)
    Dim StrTmp As String
    StrTmp = text + NbrName.ToString
End Sub
```

and unfortunately, the variable NbrName remains to 0.
Here under the whole code.

Can someone explain me where is the problem ?

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1

    Dim testbox As New AutoCompleteComboBox.SuggestComboBox
    Public NbrName As Integer

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Mika Dim testbox As New AutoCompleteComboBox.SuggestComboBox
        Me.Controls.Add(testbox)
        testbox.DataSource = New List(Of String) From {"Janean Mcgaha", "Tama Gaitan", "Jacque Tinnin", "Elvira Woolfolk", "Fransisca Owens", "Minnie Ardoin",
        "Renay Bentler", "Joye Boyter", "Jaime Flannery", "Maryland Arai", "Walton Edelstein", "Nereida Storrs",
        "Theron Zinn", "Katharyn Estrella", "Alline Dubin", "Edra Bhatti", "Willa Jeppson", "Chelsea Revel",
        "Sonya Lowy", "Danelle Kapoor"}

        NbrName = 20
    End Sub

    Public Sub SearchByName(text As String)

        Dim StrTmp As String
        StrTmp = text + NbrName.ToString


    End Sub


End Class

Namespace AutoCompleteComboBox
    Public Class SuggestComboBox
        Inherits ComboBox
#Region "fields and properties"

        Private ReadOnly _suggLb As New ListBox() With {.Visible = False, .TabStop = False}
        Private ReadOnly _suggBindingList As New BindingList(Of String)()
        Private _propertySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
        Private _propertySelectorCompiled As Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))
        Private _filterRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
        Private _filterRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, Boolean)
        Private _suggestListOrderRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
        Private _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, String)

        Public Property SuggestBoxHeight() As Integer
            Get
                Return _suggLb.Height
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                If value > 0 Then
                    _suggLb.Height = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' If the item-type of the ComboBox is not string,
        ''' you can set here which property should be used
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property PropertySelector() As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
            Get
                Return _propertySelector
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _propertySelector = value
                _propertySelectorCompiled = value.Compile()
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        ''' Lambda-Expression to determine the suggested items
        ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
        ''' <para>default: case-insensitive contains search</para>
        ''' <para>1st string: list item</para>
        ''' <para>2nd string: typed text</para>
        '''</summary>
        Public Property FilterRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
            Get
                Return _filterRule
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean)))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _filterRule = value
                _filterRuleCompiled = Function(item) value.Compile()(item, Text)
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        ''' Lambda-Expression to order the suggested items
        ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
        ''' <para>default: alphabetic ordering</para>
        '''</summary>
        Public Property SuggestListOrderRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
            Get
                Return _suggestListOrderRule
            End Get
            Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String)))
                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                _suggestListOrderRule = value
                _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = value.Compile()
            End Set
        End Property

#End Region

        ''' <summary>
        ''' ctor
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
            ' set the standard rules:
            _filterRuleCompiled = Function(s) s.ToLower().Contains(Text.Trim().ToLower())
            _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = Function(s) s
            _propertySelectorCompiled = Function(collection) collection.Cast(Of String)()

            _suggLb.DataSource = _suggBindingList
            AddHandler _suggLb.Click, AddressOf SuggLbOnClick

            AddHandler ParentChanged, AddressOf OnParentChanged
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' the magic happens here ;-)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)

            If Not Focused Then
                Return
            End If

            _suggBindingList.Clear()
            _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
            _propertySelectorCompiled(Items).Where(_filterRuleCompiled).OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled).ToList().ForEach(AddressOf _suggBindingList.Add)
            _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
            _suggBindingList.ResetBindings()

            _suggLb.Visible = _suggBindingList.Any()

            If _suggBindingList.Count = 1 AndAlso _suggBindingList.[Single]().Length = Text.Trim().Length Then
                Text = _suggBindingList.[Single]()
                [Select](0, Text.Length)
                _suggLb.Visible = False
            End If
        End Sub

#Region "size and position of suggest box"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' suggest-ListBox is added to parent control
        ''' (in ctor parent isn't already assigned)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Private Overloads Sub OnParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Parent.Controls.Add(_suggLb)
            Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(_suggLb, 0)
            _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
            _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
            _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
            _suggLb.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 9)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLocationChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnLocationChanged(e)
            _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
            _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
            _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "visibility of suggest box"

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(e As EventArgs)
            ' _suggLb can only getting focused by clicking (because TabStop is off)
            ' --> click-eventhandler 'SuggLbOnClick' is called
            If Not _suggLb.Focused Then
                HideSuggBox()
            End If
            MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
        End Sub

        Private Sub SuggLbOnClick(sender As Object, eventArgs As EventArgs)
            Text = _suggLb.Text
            Focus()
        End Sub

        Private Sub HideSuggBox()
            _suggLb.Visible = False
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(e As EventArgs)
            HideSuggBox()
            MyBase.OnDropDown(e)
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "keystroke events"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' if the suggest-ListBox is visible some keystrokes
        ''' should behave in a custom way
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnPreviewKeyDown(e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
            If Not _suggLb.Visible Then
                MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
                Return
            End If

            Select Case e.KeyCode
                Case Keys.Down
                    If _suggLb.SelectedIndex < _suggBindingList.Count - 1 Then
                        _suggLb.SelectedIndex += 1
                    End If
                    Return
                Case Keys.Up
                    If _suggLb.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
                        _suggLb.SelectedIndex -= 1
                    End If
                    Return
                Case Keys.Enter
                    Text = _suggLb.Text
                    [Select](0, Text.Length)
                    _suggLb.Visible = False

                    'Mika
                    Dim myObject As Form1 = New Form1()
                    myObject.SearchByName(Text)
                    'Mika

                    Return
                Case Keys.Escape
                    HideSuggBox()
                    Return
            End Select

            MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
        End Sub

        Private Shared ReadOnly KeysToHandle As List(Of Keys) = New List(Of Keys) From {Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape}
        Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
            ' the keysstrokes of our interest should not be processed be base class:
            If _suggLb.Visible AndAlso KeysToHandle.Contains(keyData) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
        End Function

#End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I suspect you may find your issue is in the OnPreviewKeyDown method.  In the section you've got sounded by 'Mka you're creating a new instance of the form where NbrName is declared public.  Are you sure a new instance is intended? Also I'm not seeing any reason for NbrName  to be public in the first place.  And just general comment StrTmp = text + NbrName.ToString arithmetically Adds two strings, use _&_  to concatenate strings together

Comment: Thank you. I had to implement a new instance because the SearchByName function was not called as it is another class. I tried with a shared function but It still doesn't work. NbrName remains to 0 even it is declared in the same class.

Comment: Ok, it works adding Form1.NbrName instead of just NbrName and using a shared function. I don't really understand why as I'm accessing the NbrName variable inside de Form1 class but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same name for variables within a sub and as a public variable which means that you have 2 totally separated variables. In a Sub without qualifier it is available only inside the Sub. However you want to set the Public NbrName variable which is available globally, not the one inside the Sub.
This is why the fully qualified name has to be used always for the global variable as you did it in your comment.